# Return lag value when a condition is met in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database filled automatically every 5 minutes but every day I have one hour with samples equal to zero, like this:

| Time | Power |
| --- | --- |
| 11:50 | 1800 |
| 11:55 | 1500 |
| 00:00 | 0 |
| 00:05 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 1:00 | 1600 |

And I want the query to be:

| Time | Power |
| --- | --- |
| 11:50 | 1800 |
| 11:55 | 1500 |
| 00:00 | 1500 |
| 00:05 | 1500 |
| ... | ... |
| 1:00 | 1600 |

How can I achieve this? I have read about the Coalesce but dont understand how to add the subquery for 0 value.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    Time,
    CASE
        WHEN Power <> 0 THEN Power
        ELSE ( -- need last nonzero Power
            SELECT
                Power
            FROM
                TableName X -- alias to avoid namespace confusion
            WHERE
                Power <> 0
                AND Time <= TableName.Time
            ORDER BY
                Time DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) 
    END AS Power
FROM
    TableName
ORDER BY
    Time
;
```

The subquery grabs the most recent nonzero power. I added the CASE statement for performance reasons: you don't want subqueries to run unless they need to.

Comment: It Worked Smoothly! Thank You very much.  What is the alias for? dont understan yet the logic

Comment: @ErickDavidRodriguez-Orduna When you use self-referential logic (e.g. "for each row on this table, get the last non-zero row on this same table"), you need to name (i.e. "alias") the second "version" of the table a different thing than the first. Otherwise, the database couldn't do comparisons between them! As a mental exercise, imagine removing that `X` alias in my answer. How would the system know what you meant by `WHERE Time <= TableName.Time` in that case? You would have two tables called `TableName` and no syntactical way to differentiate between them. Hope that helps.